# Extract RSSI Values off of Nest

Tags: rssi, nest-api

I was just wondering if there was any possibility of obtaining RSSI values belonging to Nest thermostats or smoke detectors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not available in the current data model.